# where does @import "compass/css3"; in zurb's foundation come from?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I'm just trying to get my head round all things SASS, Compass and the Front-end framework Foundation from Zurb.

I've got everything installed properly, and my first foundation template is setup.  Now I'm trying to configure what to include from the foundation framework.

In the foundation.scss file there is a line:

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

I can't for the life of me work out where this file is coming from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file comes from Compass itself:   http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/

Comment: Right I see.  So by using  @import "compass/css3"  am I including all of the compass variables and mixins. So, for example $default-transition-property, is available for me to use in my scss?

Comment: Everything that comes with that file and any file it includes, yes.